# Append every other line from a text file? (Python)

Tags: python, list

What I'm trying to do is append every other line in my text file into a list, and then the other lines into a serperate list? E.g.

```
Text File 'example'

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
```

So I want 'Item 1', 'Item 3' and 'Item 5' in a list called exampleOne and the other items in a list called exampleTwo?

I've tried for ages to try and work this out by myself by slicing and then appending in different ways, but I just can't seem to get it, if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read the file one line at a time and alternate the list to which you append.

Comment: So one I've opened the text file and written "for line in example:" what would I put after this to alternate the list that the line is appended to?

Comment: @IndigoOstrich Something that selects for even vs odd. The most common strategy is probably modulo 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
with open('example') as f:
    lists = [[], []]
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        lists[i].append(line.strip())
        i ^= 1

print(lists[0])  # ['Item 1', 'Item 3', 'Item 5']
print(lists[1])  # ['Item 2', 'Item 4']
```

Or simpler, with enumerate:

```
with open('example') as f:
    lists = [[], []]
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        lists[i%2].append(line.strip())

print(lists[0])  # ['Item 1', 'Item 3', 'Item 5']
print(lists[1])  # ['Item 2', 'Item 4']
```

**EDIT**

```
print(lists[0][0])  # 'Item 1' 
print(lists[0][1])  # 'Item 3'
print(lists[0][2])  # 'Item 5'
print(lists[1][0])  # 'Item 2'
print(lists[1][1])  # 'Item 4'
```

Comment: To get 'Item 1' would I print(lists[0,1]), sorry if this sounds really basic but I'm just trying to get this thing to work...

Comment: Close, `print(lists[0][0])` -- the first index is the list id, the second index is the element index in the list -- so `print lists[0][0] => 'Item 1'`,  `print lists[0][1] => 'Item 3'`, and `print lists[1][0] => 'Item 2'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import izip_longest as zip2
with open("some_file.txt") as f:
    linesA,linesB = zip2(*zip(f,f))
```

is one way you could do something like this

this basically is just abusing the fact that filehandles are iterators

Comment: When I run this with an odd number of lines (5, in my case), I lose the last line.  `print linesA, linesB => ('Item 1\n', 'Item 3\n') ('Item 2\n', 'Item 4\n')`

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I tried it but as I'm on school computers they don't allow us to import itertools, but once again thanks for your help!

Comment: I know, I tried it but they have some weird install which says the module is not available, school computers are ridiculously locked down I don't even know how they did it...